# query multiple tables with columns based on multiple conditions

Tags: t-sql

I have three columns: crew info, training info, position info. I am trying to create a report that shows the most recent date of certain trainings that each crew member has taken. Each training should have its own column but some trainings are only required for certain positions.

I have tried a case statement statement as well as just filtering in a where statement but keep getting errors. Some of the research did says that t SQL doesn't have an if statement but some says it does.

Here is the Access code that works: Ballast Water Management:

```
Max(IIf([CURRENT_FLAG]=1 And [QUALIFICATION_ID] In (14800000086) And [CMC_POS_CODE_TRANSLATOR] In (1,3,6,8,12,13,15,18,20,25,32,90,91,92,94,96,98,100,102,103,230),[ISSUED_ON],IIf([CMC_POS_CODE_TRANSLATOR] Not In (1,3,6,8,12,13,15,18,20,25,32,90,91,92,94,96,98,100,102,103,230),"","0")))
```

What I want is to either show the latest date that a crew member completed the training (if required), a blank if it's not required for them, or a 0 if it's required and they don't have it.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please take a minute to take the [tour], especially [ask].Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, one of the problems you have is that you are essentially returning three data types:

- a date (possibly even a datetime);
- a BIT (0/1);
- an empty string (VARCHAR).

So you need some way to handle all three.  I assumed that you would want:

- a date in YYYYMMDD format as a string;
- the 0 is a string of "0";
- the empty string is already a string.

So your query becomes this:

```
SELECT 
    MAX(
        CASE 
            WHEN [CURRENT_FLAG] = 1 
                AND [QUALIFICATION_ID] = 14800000086 
                AND [CMC_POS_CODE_TRANSLATOR] IN (1,3,6,8,12,13,15,18,20,25,32,90,91,92,94,96,98,100,102,103,230)
            THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [ISSUED_ON], 112)
        ELSE
            CASE 
                WHEN [CMC_POS_CODE_TRANSLATOR] NOT IN (1,3,6,8,12,13,15,18,20,25,32,90,91,92,94,96,98,100,102,103,230) 
                THEN ''
                ELSE '0'
            END
        END)
FROM
    MY_TABLE;
```

If this doesn't work what might help is showing us what you tried, and the actual error you got?

Also, TSQL does indeed allow use of `IF` statements, but not inside a `SELECT` query.  So you could do this:

```
IF @my_dog_has_no_nose = 1
BEGIN
   SELECT 'how does he smell?' AS question;
ELSE
   SELECT NULL AS question;
END;
```

But in a `SELECT` statement you will have to use `CASE` to allow redirection.

Comment: The OP is using IIF which is an alternative to the case statement and can be used in line. I imagine that your datatype returned hypothesis is the correct one though.

Comment: Thank you Richard, that makes sense. I will try it and let you know.